# how to use Linux mincore() in java

Tags: java

In java, how to find pages are resident in memory of a file.

i have found mincore() in C library,
mincore - determine whether pages are resident in memory

how to find pages of a file in memory using java?

Answer (score 1):

You need to use JNI or JNA to call mincore. It is not possible with plain Java.

You can only use mincore on memory mapped files.

There is a [library](https://github.com/indeedeng/util/blob/master/mmap/src/main/java/com/indeed/util/mmap/NativeMemoryUtils.java) that does this via JNI. I used [JNA](https://github.com/java-native-access/jna) while playing around memory mapped files for a personal project. I added the JNA code to give you a better idea.

You can use the nice [vmtouch](http://hoytech.com/vmtouch/) program to double-check the results.

```
import com.sun.jna.*;
import sun.misc.Unsafe;
import sun.nio.ch.FileChannelImpl;

import java.lang.reflect.Field;
import java.lang.reflect.Method;
import java.nio.Buffer;
import java.nio.ByteBuffer;
import java.nio.MappedByteBuffer;
import java.nio.channels.FileChannel;
import java.nio.file.Paths;
import java.nio.file.StandardOpenOption;

/**
 * Example how to access mincore function from Java.
 */
public class MincoreJava {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

        String file = "/tmp/foo.test";

        FileChannel fc = FileChannel.open(Paths.get(file), StandardOpenOption.WRITE, StandardOpenOption.READ);

        // calls mmap
        MappedByteBuffer mmaped = fc.map(FileChannel.MapMode.READ_WRITE, 0, fc.size());

        // play with this to see how it changes the output
        mmaped.put(10*4*1024, (byte)2);

        // first lets get the address of the mmap file
        // we can do this with plain Java reflection
        long nativeAddress = getNativeAddressOf(mmaped);

        // before we call the mincore we should get the value of system page size
        // we can do this with reflection
        Field unsafeField = Unsafe.class.getDeclaredField("theUnsafe");
        unsafeField.setAccessible(true);
        Unsafe unsafe = (Unsafe) unsafeField.get(null);
        int PAGE_SIZE = unsafe.pageSize();

        // we need to prepare the vec array that will hold the results
        // the vec must point to an array containing at least (length+PAGE_SIZE-1) / PAGE_SIZE bytes
        int pages = (int) ((fc.size() + (PAGE_SIZE - 1)) / (PAGE_SIZE));
        byte[] vec = new byte[pages];

        // do the mincore call using JNA (we could just as well used JNI)
        int result = CLibray.INSTANCE.mincore(nativeAddress, fc.size(), vec);

        if (result != 0) {
            throw new RuntimeException("Call to mincore failed with return value " + result);
        }

        // print out the pages
        System.out.println("File: " + file);
        System.out.println("\nOccupies " + fc.size() + " Bytes and " + pages + " Pages");

        printPageInfo(nativeAddress, PAGE_SIZE, vec);

        // we can call munmap via reflection
        unmap(mmaped);
    }

    // This is the idiomatic JNA way of dealing with native code
    // it is also possible to use native JNA methods
    // and alternatively JNI
    public interface CLibray extends Library {
         CLibray INSTANCE = (CLibray) Native.loadLibrary("c", CLibray.class);

        // int mincore(void *addr, size_t length, unsigned char *vec);
        // JNA will automagically convert the parameters to native parameters
        int mincore(long addr, long length, byte[] vec);
    }

    private static void printPageInfo(long baseAddress, int PAGE_SIZE, byte[] vec) {
        for (int i = 0; i < vec.length; i++) {
            // the least significant bit is 1 if paged
            String paged = Integer.toBinaryString(vec[i]);

            System.out.println(String.format("Page_%06d_[0x%s-0x%s]_%s", i,
                    Long.toHexString(baseAddress + i * PAGE_SIZE),
                    Long.toHexString(baseAddress + i * PAGE_SIZE + PAGE_SIZE - 1),
                    paged));
        }
    }

    private static long getNativeAddressOf(ByteBuffer map) throws Exception {
        final Field field = Buffer.class.getDeclaredField("address");

        field.setAccessible(true);
        return field.getLong(map);
    }

    public static void unmap(final MappedByteBuffer buffer) throws Exception {
        if (null != buffer) {
            final Method method = FileChannelImpl.class.getDeclaredMethod("unmap", MappedByteBuffer.class);

            method.setAccessible(true);
            method.invoke(null, buffer);
        }
    }
}
```